# ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead

Tags: netlogo

In my study, I'm trying to build a simulation representing of a real work setting, with the aim of creating knowledge on how make people feel better at work.
In particular, I'm modelling a scenario where people work for more than one team (do you work on only one project at a time? Many don't...). To do this, I'm working with NetLogo.

I'm having a problem with an ASK to a specific agent of a custom link-turtle-set. The point is that sometimes it reports an error, saying that "ASK expected input to be an agent or agentset but got NOBODY instead", but it should not arrive to that "ASK" without the agent to exist! What am I doing wrong?

The function is the following:

```
to TeamRecruiting
  ;; I ask non-complete teams to...
  ask teams with [ teamsize != (count membership-neighbors) ]
  [
    ;; ... count how many individuals they have...
    let actualteammembers count membership-neighbors
    ;; ... to save locally how many individuals they can share...
    let teamoverlap overlap
    ;; ... their target size...
    let neededsize teamsize
    ;; ... and their identity.
    let teamwho who
    ;; then I ask those individuals that have not yet more things than they can handle...
    ask individuals with [ indMTM != (count membership-neighbors) ]
      [
      ;; ... to save locally who they are...
      let indwho who
      let createdalink 0
      ;; ... then if some conditions have been met ...
      if(some conditions)
        [
        ;; I create a link (of my specific type) with the team...
        create-membership-with team teamwho
        ;; I do the following because more than one individual could join the team teamwho in the same run of the function
        ask team teamwho [ set actualteammembers (actualteammembers + 1) ]
        set createdalink 1
        ]
      ;; if the association occurred, ...
      if(createdalink = 1)
        [
        ;; we ask all other teams to evaluate if the new connection violates their maximum overlap constraint between the team I am considering from the beginning of the function, and all other teams, in other words...
        ask teams with [ who != teamwho ]
        [
        let numpaths 0
        let team2who who
        ;; I count how many individuals say that they are shared by the two teams
        ask individuals
          [
          if((membership-neighbor? team teamwho) and (membership-neighbor? team team2who)) [ set numpaths (numpaths + 1) ]
          ]
        ;; ... and if the number of paths is more than the maximum allowed overlap...
        if(numpaths > teamoverlap)
          [
          ;; I take the connection away...
          ask membership teamwho indwho [ die ]
          ;; and I reduce the actual number of team members
          set actualteammembers (actualteammembers - 1)
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Thank you for your precious help!

Comment: note: the problem happens at: ask membership teamwho indwho [ die ]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is likely to be in the way you refer to the link you are asking to die.  `membership` is an undirected link and so which agent is `end1` and which is `end2` depends upon the order in which the agents were created.  The one with the lower who number is `end1` and the other is `end2`.  So, if the team agent was created after the individual agent, that particular link would be `membership indwho teamwho`.  In general, using who numbers at all is bad practice, but the same problem would arise if you used the team and individual agents themselves rather than their who numbers.

Someone with more experience in the use of undirected links than I might have better advice on how to easily refer to an undirected link when you don't know offhand which agent is the older, but something like

```
ifelse (indwho < teamwho) [
ask membership indwho teamwho [ die ]
]
[
ask membership teamwho indwho [ die ]
]
```

should work.  Using directed links obviates this problem as the creator agent is always end1 and the target agent end2.  So, if membership links always are created by the individual, you'll always know that the individual is at end1.

Hope this helps.
Charles